# ILogger - SpanId vs TraceId vs HttpContext.TraceIdentifier

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages, ilogger

I was running code from [this repo](https://github.com/dahlsailrunner/aspnetcore-effective-logging) and generating an error from the Book.API, I get an error page like this:

[image]

The request ID is |574e8e13-4e9d31fed64d4793.

When I look at the log entry in the file, I see:

```
{
    "Timestamp": "2021-01-25T18:07:24.6565993-06:00",
    "Level": "Fatal",
    "MessageTemplate": "BADNESS!!! Cannot open database \"Demo_EffectiveLogging\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'TCA-PRECISION\\terry.aney'. -- {ErrorId}.",
    "Exception": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database \"Demo_EffectiveLogging\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'TCA-PRECISION\\terry.aney'.\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryImpl[T](IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command, Type effectiveType)+MoveNext() in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1079\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 721\r\n   at BookClub.Data.BookRepository.GetAllBooks() in C:\\Users\\terry.aney\\OneDrive\\.NET Core Tutorials\\EffectiveLogging\\BookClub.Data\\BookRepository.cs:line 33\r\n   at BookClub.Logic.BookLogic.GetAllBooks(Boolean callBadMethod) in C:\\Users\\terry.aney\\OneDrive\\.NET Core Tutorials\\EffectiveLogging\\BookClub.Logic\\BookLogic.cs:line 26\r\n   at BookClub.API.Controllers.BookController.GetBooks(Boolean throwException) in C:\\Users\\terry.aney\\OneDrive\\.NET Core Tutorials\\EffectiveLogging\\BookClub.API\\Controllers\\BookController.cs:line 45\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)\r\n   at BookClub.Infrastructure.Middleware.ApiExceptionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\\Users\\terry.aney\\OneDrive\\.NET Core Tutorials\\EffectiveLogging\\BookClub.Infrastructure\\Middleware\\ApiExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 28\r\nClientConnectionId:2daf3389-b366-4b50-b1c2-651419fd247e\r\nError Number:4060,State:1,Class:11",
    "Properties": {
        "ErrorId": "0cc05d84-e36f-4e2b-b8e0-57bf5e465046",
        "SourceContext": "BookClub.Infrastructure.Middleware.ApiExceptionMiddleware",
        "RequestId": "8000017c-000c-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb",
        "RequestPath": "/api/Book",
        "SpanId": "|303de91c-4b6f6e187de2f4f3.",
        "TraceId": "303de91c-4b6f6e187de2f4f3",
        "ParentId": ""
    }
}
{
    "Timestamp": "2021-01-25T18:07:24.8378974-06:00",
    "Level": "Error",
    "MessageTemplate": "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.",
    "Exception": "System.Exception: API Failure\r\n   at BookClub.UI.StandardHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\\Users\\terry.aney\\OneDrive\\.NET Core Tutorials\\EffectiveLogging\\BookClub.UI\\StandardHttpMessageHandler.cs:line 57\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)\r\n   at BookClub.UI.Pages.BookListModel.OnGetAsync() in C:\\Users\\terry.aney\\OneDrive\\.NET Core Tutorials\\EffectiveLogging\\BookClub.UI\\Pages\\BookList.cshtml.cs:line 27\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.NonGenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)",
    "Properties": {
        "EventId": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "UnhandledException"
        },
        "SourceContext": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware",
        "RequestId": "80000069-0004-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb",
        "RequestPath": "/BookList",
        "SpanId": "|574e8e13-4e9d31fed64d4793.",
        "TraceId": "574e8e13-4e9d31fed64d4793",
        "ParentId": ""
    }
}
```

So it appears to be matching the `SpanId` instead of the `RequestId`.

So my questions:

1. I was watching the Pluralsight course, the screen shots seemed to be showing `RequestId` properly.  How is that possible that his shows correct `RequestId` and mine shows `SpanId`?
2. I created a new project and to my knowledge, implemented everything the same way the repo did, yet I do not get `SpanId`, `TraceId`, or `ParentId` in my log properties.  Any guess to what I might have missed?
3. Should the `SpanId`'s match across WebApi and Website calls (i.e. the two logs above, the top one is Web API and second one is Web Site and both have unique Span/Request IDs)?  Or am I supposed to use CorrelationId?
4. General question, what is difference between SpanId vs TraceId vs HttpContext.TraceIdentifier?  Should my error.cshtml just use `TraceIdentifier` instead of looking at Activity.Current.Id?

**Update**: I implemented my project in .NET 5.  That might be the culprit for missing properties in log, but the rest of the questions remain valid.

**Update**: I have figured out workaround for missing properties in .NET 5.  And I also have `TraceId` spanning across calls from site to api, but I am wondering what `SpanId` represents, I'm not finding it easily on the web.

Comment: `SpanId` represents the current bit of processing. When your endpoint is called, a new `SpanId` is created. When you call another endpoint, `TraceId` is copied over, but the endpoint creates a new `SpanId`, with the `SpanId` from previous node becoming `ParentId`. That way you get end-to-end tracing.